# Imprimir ñ y tildes por consola en Powershell

Tags: c++, windows10, powershell

¿Es posible imprimir por salida estandar los acentos y ñ? En Ubuntu funcionan perfectamente, sin embargo, usando G++ y Powershell en Windows (El cual soporta acentos de por sí) aparecen problemas de codificación.

Supongo que será un porblema del compilador y/o su configuración, aunque no he encontrado nada al respecto, puesto que la gran mayoría de las páginas están en inglés y lógicamente no tratan estos temas.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de lo que estás haciendo?, en concreto me gustaría saber qué consola de salida usas (`std::cout` o `std::wcout`) y que datos de salida envías (`std::string` o `std::wstring`).

Comment: La consola de salida es std::cout, y por lo general, el texto lo mando directamente, sin hacer uso explicito de string o char *. Por ejemplo: cout << "\n\n/ ----- Grado Árbol General ----- / \n\n\t" << grado(A) << endl;

Comment: ¿Puedes **editar** la pregunta para añadir los detalles? Los comentarios no tienen garantía de persistencia (pueden ser borrados) así que es más adecuado añadir los detalles a la pregunta.